# What does a PDOStatement contain and what is the use of fetch/fetchAll?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot understand 1) what is inside a PDOStatement object and 2) why I would need a fetch() or fetchAll() method.

My database: One simple table called 'animals' with 3 columns (id, name, species).

My code:

```
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     exit( $e->getMessage() );
}

try {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM animals";
     $results = $pdo->query($sql);
     print_r($results);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

First off, print_r (or var_dump) prints this: `PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM animals )`

But if I write this:

```
foreach($results as $row) {
      echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['species'];
}
```

every content of my table is printed.

So 1) why print_r doesn't show anything of that info if it exists inside my object?

and

2) why I would need `$results->fetch()` or `$results->fetchAll()` to fetch the info I have already fetched from the database and are in the result set $results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how the API is designed, with flexibility in mind.

Your object does not contain all datasets. Instead [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/PDOStatement) implements the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/Iterator)/[`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable) interface, implicitly calling `->fetch` for each `foreach` operation.

Some people however prefer to use `->fetch` manually, or `->fetchAll` for pulling all rows at once.

Comment: So what does exactly a PDOStatement object contains? Only a property 'queryString' with the value of the SQL statement or something more?

Comment: `print_r` only shows its public properties. But it also contains a result handle, which is hidden because you can't use utilize it from PHP userland.

Comment: From php.net: print_r() will also show protected and private properties of objects with PHP 5. But as I see in PDOStatement class reference, queryString is anyway the only property and the others are methods. So I conclude that PDOStatement doesn't contain results (and isn't a result set as I read somewhere). The result set is fetched from the database when fetch() or fetchAll() is called. PDOStatement maybe is a kind of intermediate to this process. (I would still like to know its exact role but I can't figure out). What do you think?

Comment: The C implementation of all that is PDO does not expose all interna into PHP. It only populates one public property. It doesn't bother with creating private/protected ones at all. Because the PDOStatement object from PHP just references a secondary structure via its zval bucket, `pdo_stmt_t`, which contains all the interesting stuff. See https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h#L540 for some of that. You cannot access that from your PHP script.